# Why is my function not called on click?

Tags: jquery

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$('.pp').click(function()   {
    alert();
});
</script>

<p class=pp>asdf</p>
<p class=pp>asdf</p>
<p class=pp>asdf</p>
```

Why the function is not called on click event?

It must be very silly and stupid question, but I don'w know what I'm missing.

Comment: class="pp" -- the quotes are not there & the jQuery wrapper $(document).ready(function(){  //Your Code  });

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Because the [DOM hasn't been loaded yet](http://api.jquery.com/ready/):

```
$(document).ready( function() {
  // ...your code...
} );
```

Answer (score 2):

should be

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
    $('.pp').click(function(){
        alert();
    });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is purely because you are attaching a click event to a node that doesn't actually exist yet. Put the code after the HTML nodes, or call that upon the `load` or `DOMContentLoaded` events.

Answer (score 0):

or

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.pp').click(function(event){
        alert();
    });
});
</script>
```