# Why won't my jQuery trigger work?

Tags: javascript, jquery, triggers, bind

I'm just coming up to speed on jQuery, I'll apologize up front if this is a rookie error.

I'm attempting to get a simple custom trigger to fire without and success. Maybe someone can help help out and show me why this isn't working.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
<html>
  <head>
  <title>jQuery Trigger example</title>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


  <script>
  $('#asset1').bind("triggerAssets", function() {
    alert('Assets');
  });
  </script>

  <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
      $('#asset1').trigger("triggerAssets");
    });
  </script>

  </head>
  <body >
    <div id="asset1" class="assets" >Asset
        <table>
          <tr>
              <td>Field One: </td>
              <td><input type="text" name="fieldOne" id="exfieldOne" value=""/></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
              <td>Field Two: </td>
               <td><input type="text" name="fieldTwo" id="exfieldTwo" value=""/></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
              <td>Field Three: </td>
              <td><input type="text" name="fieldThree" id="exfieldThree" value=""/></td>
          </tr>
        </table>
     </div>    
    <hr>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You are creating the binding before the elements exist. Wrap the first piece of JS in `$(documnet).ready()` just like you do with the trigger.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why is my function not called on click?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3492806/why-is-my-function-not-called-on-click)

Comment: From the [jQuery tutorial](http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials:Getting_Started_with_jQuery): *"As almost everything we do when using jQuery reads or manipulates the document object model (DOM), we need to make sure that we start adding events etc. as soon as the DOM is ready. To do this, we register a ready event for the document."*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your binding function will run before the page is rendered; `#asset1` doesn't yet exist. Move it into the `ready` handler, which fires *after* the DOM is ready (and your element is present).

```
$(document).ready(function(){ // wait until the DOM is ready, then do:

  $('#asset1').bind("triggerAssets", function() {
    alert('Assets');
  });

  $('#asset1').trigger("triggerAssets");

});
```

Comment: This won't work fr me... I want to use the trigger to build elements (add/move childNodes around) before the document renders. I'm appending addins <div>s to a configuration/setting page. I wanted the trigger so each addin could place its configuration content where it wants before the page is rendered..In practice, each div would have a custom trigger handler. Now, it looks like I have to change my approach.

Comment: Well, you can't attach behaviors to elements that don't yet exist. It's a very common pattern to load up a page, and then have some js build or load in additional pieces. But you can't modify the DOM until it's ready. Just make your changes after DOMready. If you're concerned about showing incomplete chunks of the page, just hide them until the building is done, then show them as the last step.

Comment: That is the way I have to go.

Answer (score 0):

you need to bind the event either when the DOM is ready or add a delegate on future elements with id of asset1:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#asset1').bind("triggerAssets", function() {
        alert('Assets');
    });

    $('#asset1').trigger("triggerAssets");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to do something before the page is loaded, define an object to handle things like:

```
    <script>
            var test = {};
            $(test).bind("test", function(){
                alert("Your trigger was fired!");
            });

            $(test).trigger("test");

    </script>
```

Comment: The issue is the object you are binding to must exist before you can bind to it.  If the page hasn't loaded, the div you are binding to doesn't exist.